# Badge Idea: Habitue (for those who visit and contribute regularly)

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Since we already have a badge for people who have an account on SO for a year and have some reputation, why not reward those people who come to the site **regularly** and contribute to it?

- **Badge Name:** "Habitue" (aka "regular visitor")
- **Badge Value:** Silver
- **Requirements:** Visited the site for at least 365 days, posted 5
  questions, 5 answers and 5 comments.

The exact numbers are subject to discussion of course. It might be a good idea to require that the Q/A have positive scores (and in the case of questions: not closed as duplicate, subjective etc.) in order to encourage "good" usage of the site, not evil/spam.

Tell me what you think.

EDIT: okay so i thought about it a bit more. Lets change it to something like this:

- Posted a question or answer each month for twelve consecutive months with a score of at least 5. (again, values subject to discussion)

Comment: `posted 5 questions, 5 answers` Why distinguish between questions and answers? Aren't 10 upvoted answers worth the badge? So let's make it posts. And probably a bit more, for silver. I'd say 30 posts would be  ok.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: you are right, posts are probably better.

Answer (score 10):

I don't see much use in this, it partly overlaps with the question/answer-badges which are awarded for good questions/answers and with the time-badges (which you already mention). Additionally the "Yearling" badge does have the restriction that the user must have earned at least 200 rep. So basically the user had to contribute *something useful* to the site during that time. Your badge suggestion does include any *contributions*, no matter what quality.

Comment: True, but it does not capture the idea of regular contributor. Someone can come in, post a question that gets quite a bit of attention and after a week, SO might not see that person ever again. Perhaps i need to stress the idea of regularity even more, lets see...

Comment: @PeterK: So, why is it better if someone posts 5 *good* questions in a year (and drops out), instead of 5 *good* questions in a week and drops out)? Good questions are good questions, if you've got a ton of them, drop them like a bomb on SE.

Comment: Because if you do it in one week, chances are you are covering much less ground than if you can be helpful through a whole year. Of course, you are a valuable contributor for the community in both cases, but in the second case, you maintaned your value for a much longer period of time and probably helped a bigger audience, which in my opinion is worth a badge. Perhaps creating a bronze badge for the first case?

Comment: @PeterK: I don't see this, sorry. In theory, the exact opposite should be the case. Seeing that SE is one big source of knowledge, we'd better have *now* more knowledge and wisdom instead of later. But I just can't understand why stretching it like this is something better...

Comment: Sometimes even if you have a particular knowledge, it might happen that nobody needs it at the moment. But if that need ever arises and you come to SO regularly, your knowledge will be useful to others. If you don't come back, it does not matter that you know stuff, since you won't share it. Anyway i understand your point and it seems that Meta is with you on this :)

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other. Of course there should be regular contributions, because of these the site grows. But it doesn't matter in what timespan a user contributes all that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to change your idea slightly:

- Interacted (voted, posted, commented) with the site for 365 (not necessarily consecutive) days.

This would make it a stronger badge than the existing yearly, commentator, and similar badges that are awarded just from time *or* participation, as this badge would require both time and participation over time.

Comment: Good idea. Exactly what i want to achieve - reward people who use the site in a good way regularly for an extended period of time. Please see my edit of the proposal, perhaps now it will be to your liking.

Comment: @PeterK I'm not a fan of the 12 month, 5 posts voted 5+ each idea.  Too complicated.

Comment: Drop that 5 posts requirement, the new requirement i posted should not be merged with the old one. Just at least one good post each month for 12 months in a row, thats it.